# 3 Vectors dot product orthogonal

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

Let there be vectors v and w in Rn, and another vector, u is equal to kw, where k is a scalar. For what value of k is (v-u) orthogonal to w?

I did this:

> $$ ( \vec v - \vec u)\cdot \vec w=0$$
>   $$ ( \vec v - k\vec w)\cdot \vec w=0$$
>   $$  \vec v\cdot \vec w - k\vec w\cdot \vec w=0$$
>   $$  \vec v = k\vec w$$

And now I do not know what to do. Since you cannot divide vectors right? and the answer basically says v and w are in the same direction. But I don't see where I went wrong during the steps. So if someone could help that would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last step is wrong. You cannot divide vectors, as you say, hence from 
$$ (v \cdot w) = k(w \cdot w)$$
it does **not** follow, that
 $$ v = kw $$
("dividing by $w$"). Instead, you can divide by the number(!) $w \cdot w$, giving 
$$ k = \frac{v \cdot w}{w \cdot w} $$